# WTelegramClient ban account

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Good afternoon friends; please advise.
I used the WTelegramClient library.
Did everything as described on the Readme page
And right after that, my account was blocked.
What have I done wrong?

The code I used

```cs
static string Config(string what)
{
    switch (what)
    {
        case "api_id": return "YOUR_API_ID";
        case "api_hash": return "YOUR_API_HASH";
        case "phone_number": return "+12025550156";
        case "verification_code": Console.Write("Code: "); return Console.ReadLine();
        case "first_name": return "John";      // if sign-up is required
        case "last_name": return "Doe";        // if sign-up is required
        case "password": return "secret!";     // if user has enabled 2FA
        default: return null;                  // let WTelegramClient decide the default config
    }
}
...
using var client = new WTelegram.Client(Config);
```

I need to check if the user is registered in telegram and, if yes, return his ID.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️*Reminder: WTelegramClient is an independently developed library for accessing Telegram Client API. We are not affiliated with Telegram Teams and cannot help you with problems with your account.*

All we know about Telegram banning accounts is explained [in this FAQ](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/FAQ.md#prevent-ban).

Sensitive operations on a brand new (VOIP?) account using API calls (instead of official GUI clients) are under scrutiny from Telegram teams to prevent abuse.

You have to make sure to follow Telegram [Terms of Service](https://telegram.org/tos) as well as the [API Terms of Service](https://core.telegram.org/api/terms).

If you think your phone number was banned from Telegram for the wrong reason, you may try to contact recover@telegram.org, explaining what you were doing.